Why Did Sartre Regret “Existentialism is a Humanism”?
Why did Sartre regret his essay Existentialism is a Humanism?
Background and Evidence
Existentialism is a Humanism is an essay published by Jean-Paul Sartre in 1946. In an introduction by Mary Warnock to an edition of Being and Nothingness (also linked to by the Wikipedia article on Existentialism is a Humanism), Mary Warnock writes

It has sometimes been suggested that Sartre's positive approach to moral philosophy was outlined in the essay "Extentialism is a Humanism," first published in 1946. This essay has been translated several times into English, and it became, for a time, a popular starting-point in discussions of existentialist thought. It contained the doctrine that existentialism was a basically hopeful and constructive system of thought, contrary to popular belief, since it encouraged man to action by teaching him that his destiny was in his own hands. Sartre went on to argue that if one believes that each man is responsible for choosing freedom for himself, one is committed to believing also that he is responsible for choosing freedom for others, and that therefore not only was existentialism active rather than passive in tendency, but it was also liberal, other-regarding and hostile to all forms of tyranny. However, I mention this essay here only to dismiss it, as Sartre himself has dismissed it. He not only regretted its publication, but also actually denied some of its doctrines in later works.


SEP:"One of the reasons... for his discomfort is the clarity with which it exhibits the major tenets of existentialist thought while revealing Sartre's attempt to broaden its social application in response to his Communist and Catholic critics." Course Hero:"he feared that many of his theses would be misinterpreted by a general readership. He explained he'd had to "weaken" the philosophical language of the text for publication."

It's so sad, when you have to ruin your great idea to make it understandable! Who was it said that you should be able to explain your idea to a seven year old or you don't understand it yourself? Some fool I guess.

@andrós Have you also read Being and Nothingness? Compared to that, his lecture is a staple of clarity.
